# How to tell Users that a Tooltip lies behind a Text/Textbox/Image, etc.?

Tags: windows, user-interface, text, tooltip, user-experience

In my U.I. I have a normal text headline that covers a block of checkboxes but without further information I'm scared of Users not knowing what to do with the window. So my idea was to put a tooltip in the headline to give Users information about the funktion of my window. But how do i make clear that there actually is a tooltip behind that headline? I dont think people would normally hover over the headline so they would never get the information. Is there some sort of specific system to imply that there will be a tooltip over a control or text (like some special cursor)?

Comment: Maybe add a small button with a question mark and put the same tooltip on that one.  People will instinctively move the mouse over the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a small info icon next to the header, so the user will know that there is more information hidden.

Hope that this idea help you!

Answer (score 0):

When the form opens, you could move the mouse to the headline.

Or add a little something to attract the attention like a button or image and add the same tooltip there..